# What happened on June 17, 2016 with the DAO?

Tags: the-dao

It seems the DAO [was attacked](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4oi2ta/i_think_thedao_is_getting_drained_right_now/). What exactly happened? What can be done?

Comment: You can find some info [here](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/06/17/critical-update-re-dao-vulnerability/) and [here](http://vessenes.com/more-ethereum-attacks-race-to-empty-is-the-real-deal/)